# Propositional Logic False S

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The original question was: How many are speaking truth in the conversation?

Here is how I am addressing the problem:

I would get to this:

1. $¬B$
2. $C$
3. $A$
4. $¬A \land ¬B \land ¬C$
5. $¬A \land ¬C$

This set, has a contradiction, from which I can presume that B is lying at some point. However, there is the possibility that B is telling the truth and at the same time lying. I was considering, modelling this like:

$B \rightarrow C \land ¬A \land ¬C$, (like saying, if B is telling the truth, then it must be the case that...), however this does not model when B might be a truth-teller or a liar, because if B is telling the truth there is a contradiction... How should I address this? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements are not binary: we have (1) a truth teller: all statements are true, (2) always lies: all false (3) told a lie: at least one statement is.

*$A_1$ said "B always lies"*:  If that stement, $A_1$, is true. Then $B$ always lies (all statements $B_1$ and $B_2$ are false). Conversely, if one of $B_i$ is true, then statement $A_1$ is false.

$$A_1 = \lnot (B_1 \lor B_2)$$

*$B_1$: "C is a truth-teller":* Similarly, $B_1$ is true iff all $C_i$ are true, but there is only $C_1$, thus

$$B_1 = C_1$$

*$C_1$: "A told the truth"*:

$$C_1 = A_1$$

*$D_1$ "None of A, B, and C is a truth-teller"*

$$D_1 = \lnot (A_1 \lor B_1 \lor B_2 \lor C_1) = (\lnot A_1 \land \lnot B_1 \land \lnot B_2 \land \lnot C_1)$$

*$B_2$: "Both A and C told lies"*. Meaning there is $i, j$ such that $A_i$ and $C_j$ are false. But there is only $A_1$ and $C_1$. Thus,

$$B_2 = (\lnot A_1 \land \lnot C_1)$$

Then, it is easy to verify that $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1$ are false, and $B_2$ is true.

Comment: Ok, I understand it, thanks for the answer. However, what happens in the case that I don't know whether people is telling the truth, or lying or is ambiguous? How can I model that situation? (knowing that anyone could be a truth teller, a liar or ambiguous)

Comment: You can model the situation as above, as you mainly end up with a number of "equations" that may or may not lead to a contradiction. Perhaps your question is how to check for consistency among them?

Comment: it was easier for me to start with C.

Comment: My question is, how to model the situation in which I do not know who tells the truth, who lies, and who tells truths and lies. How to relate honesty levels using prepositional logic,

Comment: If no one seems to lies, based on the (logical) consistency of their statements, what makes you believe they might be dishonest? Define honesty level?

Comment: Well, something like: B cannot be telling the truth, because it would not be consistent. C and D cannot be telling the truth at the same time, because consistency would be lost. Like what Reiter proposed in his model-based diagnosis